# persisted java entity reference issue

Tags: java, reference, persistence

I am working on a personal project, and i have a strange issue which i can't seem to solve, even after many hours of research and debugging, so obviously it must be somehting very simple i'm ignoring ....
Anyway, the context is : JPA + PostgresSQL + Glassfish.
I have an entity (generated by netbeans), MvUser, with:

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id")
@SequenceGenerator(name="mv_user_autoincrement_gen",sequenceName     ="mv_user_autoincrement",allocationSize=1)  
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator="mv_user_autoincrement_gen") 
private Long id;
```

Then, i have an AbstractFacade with generics for all the boilerplate persistence code.
Here i have a method which doesn't do much, just:

```
@Override
public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}
```

Now, let's say i call this in my service class:
First i inject my facade:

```
@EJB
IMvUserFacade userFacade;
```

then i'll use it:

```
@Override
public void saveUser(MvUser user)
{
    userFacade.create(user);
    // more business specific code follows
}
```

I make a call to the service like this

```
MvUser = new MvUser();
... setters etc
mvUserService.saveUser(user);
```

Now, what is happening is that in the create method the object is persisted, i have the generated id and everything.
Because on the whole chain i have object parameters, i'm presuming that at the saveUser level the same object will be found, but no, i am left with a detached entity.
What i'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to search for the object you saved in create(). I think the object is not yet persisted to database, what you retrieve is the object from first-level cache, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm, since you are still within transaction. If you try to retrieve the object as follow and the method saveUser() is not within transaction you will get the user object from database (but detached since outside transaction):

```
public void saveUser(MvUser user)
{
userFacade.create(user);
userFacade.get(userId);
// more business specific code follows
}
```

Comment: No, i don't want to search it, but as i pass object references on the whole chain, i expect that, if at the Facade level the object is attached and has an generated id, to have the same thing at the service level, as i passed a "pointer", havn't i?



So, at the Facade level i do: getEntityManager.persist(user); i am updating the same object which was called with mvUserService.saveUser(user);

Comment: The object is not yet persisted, of course, but the identity key is allready generated.

Comment: I may be wrong but here I did it for JPA: POJO mergedPojo = em.merge(pojo). From memory, the extra **POJO mergedPojo =** is not required if you are using pure Hibernate, no JPA

Comment: Well, what i don't understand is why the persisted object, with a generated id 1) it is not managed 2) it is not updated as a reference, as in the callee method i've lost the generated id, so i presume that a copy of the object was made. If i do what you tell me i will surely break the object's reference as i create a new object, the mergedPojo.

Comment: id is generated from db sequence when your transaction is not yet committed (ie. in cache). Id generation and committing transaction are 2 different things. It's just like if you are using pure JDBC, your transaction can rollback but your the generated sequence is never returned. If you are not happy with how JPA did it, you can use Hibernate. It will do exactly what you want, you do not need to reassign the managed pojo to a new variable. Any reason you prefer JPA?

Comment: no real reason, in fact the whole process works, it's just that i didn't understood why the change didn't propagate, that's all. Thanks for the hints!